# How to Schedule API requests

Tags: rest, api, httprequest

Are you aware of any online service accessible via REST API  that can schedule calls to APIs specifically HTTP POST of `Content-Type:application/json` and `application/xml`?

Comment: Postman wasn't mentioned but the Postman Monitors are a good solution. You're limited in the number of monthly calls for the fee account though.https://www.postman.com/api-monitor/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, my service https://posthook.io lets you schedule requests back to your API through a simple REST API.

Answer (score 4):

Using AWS, I've done the following:

- Create Lambda function to `POST` to the REST API
- Create CloudWatch Events rule to trigger the Lambda function on a schedule

Here's some info on "Creating a CloudWatch Events Rule That Triggers on a Schedule"

- Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/Create-CloudWatch-Events-Scheduled-Rule.html

Answer (score 0):

https://postbacks.io is a simple, easy to use service for this. You get 10,000 free requests when you sign up. To request a callback you simply call:

```
POST https://api.postbacks.io/v1/requestPostback
```

with a request body:

```
{
    "url": "<your endpoint here>",
    "send_at": 1579787814,
    "body_string": "<any request body to pass along to your endpoint>"
}
```

Postbacks only processes callbacks every minute, but it's extremely reliable.

Answer (score -1):

I no longer host this at https://delayedrequest.com . However, the code can be found here: https://bitbucket.org/khausam/delayedrequest . It makes use of the GCP Cloud Tasks service. See the index.html file in the repo for other FAQ.

Comment: this link is not valid and does a weird redirect